# Cannot launch the latest drcsim

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi.

I tried to launch drcsim like this:

```
$ roslaunch atlas_utils qual_task_1.launch
```

then gazebo process dies generating the following message:

```
Warning [gazebo_main.cc:62] escalating to SIGKILL on client
```

Here is the specification of my PC:

- Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit
- ROS : fuerte
- drcsim : 2.6.2-1~precise
- gazebo : 1.8.1-1~precise

Moreover, I can successfully launch drcsim like this:

```
$ optirun roslaunch atlas_utils qual_task_1.launch
```

What is the cause of this problem?
Is there any way to launch drcsim without optirun?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3026/cannot-launch-the-latest-drcsim/) by [snozawa](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/371/snozawa/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

We had lots of trouble with the Optimus GPU setup.  We did once [configure](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/DRCKickoffLaptops) a bunch of Thinkpads with Optimus GPUs in them for use in a workshop.   That process worked well enough, though we still had a "black screen of death problem," wherein Gazebo would sometimes launch with a blank GUI window.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0